# Projective Geometry with Clifford Algebra - lost Inner Product

Tags: soft-question, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, clifford-algebras

Projective geometry may be studied with the tools of Clifford Algebras by adding a new direction (see for example this [article](http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/pdf-preAdobe8/PGwithCA.pdf)). But as far as I understand it, only blades and null spaces are used for this description of projective geometry. So the inner product in the base vector space, whatever crucial for the clifford product, is no longer meaningful when working in projective geometry.

**Are these statements right? Is projective geometry completely unrelated to the metric of the base vector space?**

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: It depends on what you mean, I think. "metric" in the sense of angles and distances does not have any place in projective geometry: however, the choice of metric you use when building a Clifford algebra to do projective geometry in definitely affects the structure and properties of your model.

Comment: @rschwieb This is the point: that the structure and properties of the model do not seem to be affected by the metric. More concretely, the vector spaces defined by $v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k$ do not depend on the metric, just on the linear dependence.

Comment: All of the models for projective geometry I know of in geometric algebra rely on null vectors, which necessitate indefinite metrics. So I just don't know why you think the metric does not come into play. It is apparently vital for supplying the behavior you need in the algebra. Or, if you prefer, the *signature* is definitely important, although the particular metric that makes the signature might not be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when working with projective geometry using clifford algebra, one needs to take care that one's results do not depend on the metric of the base space.

However, that doesn't mean one has to avoid the metric completely; rather, one just needs to use metrical products in combinations that are non-metrical.

For example, consider a 2d projective geometry, embedded in 3d Euclidean space.  One can find the intersection of two affine lines as follows: model the two lines as bivectors $A, B$ and then find the dual of the commutator product:

$$p = I^{-1}(A \times B)$$

This does not depend on the metric of the base space--or at least, it doesn't depend on any more than the metric of the projected space.  If the third direction, orthogonal to the projected space, is annihilated in the commutator product, multiplication with the pseudoscalar puts it back.

So when doing projective geometry, we do not need to abandon metrical operations completely, but we do need to ensure that our final results have no net dependence on the metric of the base space.

Comment: @Mumphrid So one may forget the geometric product and work only with wedge product. Is that right? In this case, why is it said that Clifford Algebras are a useful approach to projective geometry?

Comment: No, in my example above, I use metrical products (like the geometric product) multiple times in a way that cancels out the metric dependence. That, to me, is why clifford algebra *is* useful: the ability to do those manipulations as part of the algebra.